# Entity Framework auto relacionamento habilitar delete em cascata

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orientação-a-objetos

Como criar uma deleção em cascata, em um auto-relacionamento usando o `fluent api` e habilitar isso no `entity framework`?

Código:

```
 Public class Usuario {

    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public int? ObjPaiID { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario ObjPai { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Usuario> ListaPartes { get; set; }
}
```

Contexto:

```
//Auto-relacionamento Projeto
   modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
   .HasOptional(p => p.ObjPai)
   .WithMany(p => p.ListaPartes)
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.ObjPaiID);
```

Comment: Creio eu que se você habilitar no banco, e dá um update no Modelo do Entity, isso já aconteçe.

Comment: Resolvido o problema?

Comment: Não amigo, optei em fazer de outra forma. Tive que varrer a lista dos filhos do objeto e deletá-los através de um loop.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o `.WillCascadeOnDelete();`

Exemplo:

```
//Auto-relacionamento Projeto
   modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
   .HasOptional(p => p.ObjPai)
   .WithMany(p => p.ListaPartes)
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.ObjPaiID)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```