# Deletar registro de relacionar utilizando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Bom dia.
Estou trabalhando com Entity Framework e estou com problema em update de uma tabela relacional.
Por exemplo, tenho um produto com diversas categorias, na edição eu desvinculo a categoria x do produto.
O update não exclui o produto desvinculado da tabela relacional, hoje tenho que excluir tudo da relacionar para recadastrar.
Existe alguma solução automática para o método update do Entity já realizar esta exclusão da relacional quando a categoria é desvinculada?

Comment: Pode por favor colocar na sua pergunta como está o relacionamento entre Produto e Categoria?

Comment: Resolvido o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o .WillCascadeOnDelete(); Em seu contexto

Exemplo:

```
//Auto-relacionamento Projeto
   modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
   .HasOptional(p => p.ObjPai)
   .WithMany(p => p.ListaPartes)
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.ObjPaiID)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode habilitar a deleção em cascata do "EF".

[Entity Framework auto relacionamento habilitar delete em cascata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47893/entity-framework-auto-relacionamento-habilitar-delete-em-cascata)

Porem eu particularmente não acho uma boa ideia tendo em vista que você podem adicionar uma tabela como filha e apagar o registro por engano. Normalmente quando passo por esses problemas eu prefiro chamar o método de Exclusão de todas as entidade filhas antes de excluir o pai. Logicamente tudo dentro de uma transição "Begin tran" .

Answer (score 0):

Realizei um teste aqui e não noticiei o seu problema.
Em todo caso vou descrever o que fiz, pode ser que lhe ajude.

Criei as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categoria](
    [CategoriaID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Categoria] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoriaID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Produto](
    [ProdutoID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Descricao] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Produto] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProdutoID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProdutoCategoriaLink](
    [ProdutoID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CategoriaID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProdutoCategoriaLink] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProdutoID] ASC,
    [CategoriaID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProdutoCategoriaLink]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProdutoCategoriaLink_Categoria] FOREIGN KEY([CategoriaID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Categoria] ([CategoriaID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProdutoCategoriaLink] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProdutoCategoriaLink_Categoria]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProdutoCategoriaLink]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProdutoCategoriaLink_Produto] FOREIGN KEY([ProdutoID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Produto] ([ProdutoID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProdutoCategoriaLink] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProdutoCategoriaLink_Produto]
GO
```

Após inserir alguns dados, fiquei com os seguintes registros, note que a minha `ProdutoCategoriaLink` possui **12 registros**.

```
CategoriaID Descricao
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           Categoria 03
2           Categoria 04
3           Categoria 01
4           Categoria 02

ProdutoID   Descricao
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           Produto 01
2           Produto 02
3           Produto 03
4           Produto 04

ProdutoID   CategoriaID
----------- -----------
1           1
1           3
1           4
2           2
2           3
2           4
3           2
3           3
3           4
4           1
4           2
4           4
```

Configurei o meu mapeamento da seguinte forma:

```
public partial class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public Contexto()
        : base("name=Contexto")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Categoria>()
            .Property(e => e.Descricao)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Categoria>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Produtos)
            .WithMany(e => e.Categorias)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ProdutoCategoriaLink").MapLeftKey("CategoriaID").MapRightKey("ProdutoID"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>()
            .Property(e => e.Descricao)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}

[Table("Produto")]
public partial class Produto
{
    public Produto()
    {
        Categorias = new HashSet<Categoria>();
    }

    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
}

[Table("Categoria")]
public partial class Categoria
{
    public Categoria()
    {
        Produtos = new HashSet<Produto>();
    }

    public int CategoriaID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

Por fim executei o seguinte código para excluir uma categoria de cada produto:

```
using (var contexto = new Contexto())
{
    var random = new Random(0);
    foreach (var produto in contexto.Produtos)
    {                    
        var skip = random.Next(3);
        var categoria = produto.Categorias.Skip(skip).First();
        produto.Categorias.Remove(categoria);
    }

    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Ao fazer um select na minha `ProdutoCategoriaLink`, obtive os seguintes registros, note que agora tenho apenas **8 registros**.

```
ProdutoID   CategoriaID
----------- -----------
1           1
1           3
2           2
2           3
3           2
3           3
4           1
4           4
```